# What is my function missing? (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a function which prints the number of characters whose frequency is above a threshold value... (n needs to be a single non-negative number)

```
import urllib
txt = urllib.urlopen("http://students.informatics.unimelb.edu.au/~ivow/info1dev/mywork/info1media/data/moby.txt").read()

tally = {}
for char in txt:
    if char in tally:
        tally[char] += 1
    else:
        tally[char] = 1

char = 'b'

def freq_threshold(n):
    if tally[char] > n:
        return tally[char]

freq_threshold(3)
```

I want my function to return the tally of the number of times char appears in the text only if the tally is greater than my freq_threshold(n). Currently, it returns nothing..

Comment: the function doesn't return anything

Comment: In general, you should explain your *exact* problem in the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post. I know there are easier ways to do what I'm trying to accomplish, but why isn't my functioning returning a number? In the URL I used b occurs 9 times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function doesn't return anything because, the count of `b` is lesser than the threshold. In that case, it will return `None` by default. Anyway, you need to print the returned value like this

```
print freq_threshold(3)
```

but if you want to display all the characters whose count is greater than the threshold, then you need to iterate the dictionary like this

```
def freq_threshold(n):
    return [(char, tally[char]) for char in tally if tally[char] > n]
```

This will print all the characters whose count is greater than 3, along with the actual count itself.

Anyway, a better way to solve your problem would be to use `collections.Counter` and accepting the count of the character to be checked as well as a parameter, like this

```
import urllib, collections
txt = urllib.urlopen("http://www.blahblahblah.com").read()

tally = collections.Counter(txt)

def freq_threshold(char, n):
    if tally[char] > n:
        return tally[char]

print freq_threshold('b', 3)
```

**Note:** You need to specify the protocol being used in the `urlopen` call.

Comment: @ZoeIngrid I am getting `9`, are you printing the returned value, like I have shown in my answer?